# How can I create a customization point for an inline variable template?

Tags: c++, c++17

What's the best way to introduce an inline variable template so that it must be specialized for custom types? For example,

```
template<typename T> constexpr inline T max_value_v;

struct S {
    int m = 0;
};
static_assert(max_value_v<S>.m == 0);
```

[compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/w3DLiqRKuBWmw3oy) on GCC. The intent is that `max_value_v<T>` only works when it has been specialized for `T`. But the declaration of `max_value_v` is also a definition (which is default-initialized) so `max_value_v<S>` is accepted.

Is there a way to force the author of `S` to specialize `max_value_v` so that only the intended value of `max_value_v<S>` is provided to users?

Comment: Note that I am not really happy with my answer. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Note: `max_value_v` isn't value initialized, but default initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rakete1111's answer inspires this solution that involves using a deleted free function to disable the primary template:

```
template<typename T> T deleted_function() = delete;
template<typename T> constexpr inline T max_value_v = deleted_function<T>();
```

Now, unless `max_value_v` is specialized for `S`, it will not compile because it's vlue relies on deleted function, `deleted_function<S>()`.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far but it's not entirely satisfactory. If anyone can find a cleaner solution, I'll gladly accept it instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to force the author of `S` to specialize `max_value_v` so that only the intended value of `max_value_v<S>` is provided to users?

It appears not. `S` can be default-initialized, so the primary template applies.

> What's the best way to introduce an inline variable template so that it must be specialized for custom types?

You can provide a class template as the customization point:

```
template<typename T> struct max_value;
template<typename T> constexpr inline T max_value_v = max_value<T>::value;
```

Now, the author of `S` must specialize `max_value` in order for `max_value_v<S>` to compile:

```
template<>
struct max_value<S> {
    static constexpr S value { INT_MAX };
};

static_assert(max_value_v<S>.m == INT_MAX);
```

Comment: Note: this is no longer my preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is to make a function instead of a variable:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T max_value() = delete;
```

Now to use `max_value` with a `T`, you have to specialize `max_value`:

```
// without this specialization the static_assert would not compile
template<>
constexpr S max_value() {
    return{};
}

static_assert(max_value<S>().m == 0);
```

Comment: That's quite a robust solution except that `max_value` is not a variable template.